# Programming questions moving to StackOverflow

Tags: discussion

There are many programming questions in Arduino (there is even a tag for it).
However, some are not related to Arduino, like

[What happens if I pass a temporary reference and store it as a class member?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/68861/what-happens-if-i-pass-a-temporary-reference-and-store-it-as-a-class-member)

There is a flag/close/offtopic because/This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network option, but StackOverflow is not mentioned as possible candidate.

So far I flag the question and ask a moderator to move, but what is the preferred solution?

Just closing down the question, seems also not useful, especially if it can be answered while it is in Arduino StackExchange (even though it will be moved preferably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a flag/close/offtopic because/This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network option, but StackOverflow is not mentioned as possible candidate.

If you are referring to the "Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > Migration" window, I believe users with the required reputation can "see" this option but can't select a site to "migrate to". If the user can't select an option, then this option should not be displayed. Let's give the other moderators some time to see this question and hear what they know/have to say about this issue.

> So far I flag the question and ask a moderator to move, but what is the preferred solution?

Flagging the question and asking a moderator to move it is the preferred solution. Arduino SE moderators may discuss questions with the other SE network moderators before we migrate a question to them.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did (and it already has been done by the moderators).

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with VE7JRO here. I'm a little opposed to questions being migrated on technicalities, however if it has to be done, then flagging for a moderator to do it is the way. If the question had contained an Arduino function call, then it might have been more ambiguous as to whether it belonged here or not.

Comment: Shouldn't the "flag/close/offtopic because/This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network option" include the ability to choose another SE site? I seem to have the rep to point questions to the meta site, but not to an actual destination site. Given that close requests take several consensus votes before they actually take effect, this seems like it should let the voter pick a suggested destination SE site.

Comment: @DuncanC - One possible solution would be to Vote to Close with the Off-Topic reason, then flag the question with "in need of moderator intervention". Please let us know which site you would like it migrated to. I'm "pretty sure" that close votes are removed during the migration process, but you still should retain your "close vote count".